# Where do I find Crimbo Schematics?

Tags: kingdom-of-loathing

Where do I find Crimbo Schematics? I have heard of people getting Crimbo Schematics such as the Tripod or the Wrecking Ball, but I do not see the wiki giving any information and the information online isn't there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The schematics drop rarely from any combat in the Kingdom.

The wiki usually is slow to update, but for anything regarding Crimbo [this](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Crimbo) should be the page to check for news. At the moment it seems that the schematics still don't do anything.

Comment: Neato, just got two tripod schematics, pretty cool